# Sidebar only returns image placeholder

Tags: magento-1.9, image, ce-1.9.2.4, placeholder

I've multiple sidebars on my website.

1 of them is showing images correctly. But the last one (recently ordered products) is only showing the default magento placeholder.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code used in the `sidebar.phtml` to retrieve the image:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    <img
        style="width: 50px; float: right; border: 1px solid lightgray; border-radius: 6px; padding: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"
        src="<?php $_product = $_item->getProduct();
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50); ?>"/>
</a>
```

How can I retrieve the actual product image (thumbnail) instead of the magento default placeholder?

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579783/add-small-and-base-image-on-same-page-magento/18579834#18579834), but this ain't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this:

Replace the code inside "src" attribute in your image for this one:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail');
```

In order for you to get the thumbnail, I think, you need to load the product and `$_item->getProduct()` is not enough for that so simply change that to:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
```

and you should be good to go.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: You welcome @Mand, glad I could help!

Comment: In your code not get product data bcz your load item id 

   <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());?>

Comment: Yor must be load    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>

Comment: @Abdul That does not work exactly like that, everything depends on how the $_item was defined, if it was inside a foreach for instance it can be retrieved in multiple ways, since you have not loaded any product yet you cannot assume getProductId() is right way to go, so you can just do getId()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());?>
<a href="<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail');  ?>"/>
</a>
```

**OR**

```
<?php $_product = $_item->getProduct();?>
<a href="<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');  ?>"/>   
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! your first solution gives me a  "failed to open file error" And your other solution also gives me a placeholder.

Comment: updated ans pls check now